# MySQL Moving daterange with set interval

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT messageDatestamp 
     , count(messageDatestamp)  
  From table 
 where messageDatestamp between '2019-01-01 07:25:42' AND date_add('2019-01-01 07:25:45' , INTERVAL 1 SECOND)  
 group 
    by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messageDatestamp)  
 ORDER 
    BY messageDatestamp asc;
```

messageDatestamp Column data

```
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:43
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:44
2019-01-01 07:25:45
2019-01-01 07:25:45
2019-01-01 07:25:45
2019-01-01 07:25:45
2019-01-01 07:25:45
```

Output

```
2019-01-01 07:25:43, 6
2019-01-01 07:25:44, 11
2019-01-01 07:25:45, 12
```

I don't want to execute a select statement for each daterange where the end date is increment every one second like the example below.

between '2019-01-01 07:25:42' and '2019-01-01 07:26:43'

between '2019-01-01 07:25:42' and '2019-01-01 07:26:44'

between '2019-01-01 07:25:42' and '2019-01-01 07:26:45'

Is there a way to increment the end date or add the previous count value using one query?

This is what I would like the MySQL to output.

```
2019-01-01 07:25:43, 6  (Count is between  07:25:42 and  07:25:43)
2019-01-01 07:25:44, 17 (Count is between  07:25:42 and  07:25:44)
2019-01-01 07:25:45, 22 (Count is between  07:25:42 and  07:25:45)
```

Comment: How is 22 calculated?  I would understand 23 or 29, but not 22.

Comment: What type is messageDatestamp?  Just asking because fields that have stamp in their name are often VARCHAR.

Comment: Their type is datetime

Comment: between  07:25:42 and  07:25:45 the total rows are 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to increment the end date or add the previous count value using one query?

You can use `lag()`:

```
SELECT MIN(messageDatestamp), COUNT(*),
       (COUNT(*) + LAG(COUNT(*), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(messageDatestamp))
       ) as cnt_2
FROM table 
WHERE messageDatestamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 07:25:42' AND date_add('2019-01-01 07:25:45' , INTERVAL 1 SECOND)  
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messageDatestamp) 
ORDER BY messageDatestamp asc;
```

EDIT:

I see, I misunderstood your question.  You simply want a cumulative count:

You can use `lag()`:

```
SELECT MIN(messageDatestamp), COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*))OVER (ORDER BY MIN(messageDatestamp)) as cnt_2
FROM table 
WHERE messageDatestamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 07:25:42' AND date_add('2019-01-01 07:25:45' , INTERVAL 1 SECOND)  
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messageDatestamp) 
ORDER BY messageDatestamp asc;
```

Comment: The issue with this is it needs to add all previous count values before the current one being calculated else all it is doing is just shift by two.It will not work past the first two counts as intended. For   07:25:45 it should be cnt_2 + count(*) which would  = 17 +  5 = 22

Comment: @LiamHendricks . . . I did not understand your example.  You said you wanted to add the value in a current row to the previous count -- not the previous *cumulative* count.  You simply want a cumulative sum.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly  the result I need;sorry for the confusion I was trying to think of the correct terminology for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In MySql 8.0 one can SUM OVER a normal COUNT.
With an ORDER BY that SUM OVER will calculate a cumulative total.

If the messageDatestamp is a `TIMESTAMP(6)` then to compare it could be truncated to the seconds.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(messageDatestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS messageDatestamp
,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(messageDatestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS CumulativeCount
FROM `table` t
WHERE messageDatestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 07:25:42')
  AND messageDatestamp < TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 07:25:45','00:00:01')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(messageDatestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
ORDER BY messageDatestamp ASC;
```

Using DATE_FORMAT here to truncate the timestamp to seconds.
Since [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) might cause a problem in the year 2038.

**UPDATE**

If  `messageDatestamp` is a `DATETIME(0)` then it doesn't need to be truncated to the seconds.
Then the SQL can be golf-coded.

```
SELECT messageDatestamp
,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY messageDatestamp) AS CumulativeCount
FROM `table` t
WHERE messageDatestamp >= '2019-01-01 07:25:42'
  AND messageDatestamp <= '2019-01-01 07:25:45'
GROUP BY messageDatestamp
ORDER BY messageDatestamp ASC;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59623bfee71fd933e5f24aa45e5d0ae3)*